# Android WebView : Chrome Causing Issues on Methods

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, webview, onbackpressed

I have an WebApp opening my site inside `webview`. It was working smoothly until Chrome got updated to a version 63.0.3239.11
Suddenly some methods like `WebView.goback()` from `WebView` stopped working. Many users from android version 5.0 and higher reported the issue. While testing it again I uninstalled the updates of chrome and found it worked fine. Why Chrome is causing the issue? Here is my code snippet -

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    if(wb.canGoBack())
     {
       wb.goBack();
     }
   else {
        //Some Logic to Show a Dialog
      } 
    }
```

**Provided wb is my `WebView`**

Is there any way to resolve the issue apart from downgrading Chrome?

Comment: create own history stack of HTML files and handle the back button functionality within the app.

Comment: @USKMobility Is there any other way apart from this?